# achieve a theorem like construct without newtheorem

Tags: beamer, theorems

I am trying to achieve a `theorem` like representation in my `beamer` presentation as shown.

Currently I am defining a `newtheorem` env for each such construct in `preamble`, and then using that, as:

```
%in preamble
\newtheorem{trial}{A trial}

%in the body
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{trial}
      Just a trial
    \end{trial}
  \end{frame}
```

Can I have a more generic way of achiving this? I mean, I don't want to define 50 `\newtheorem` in `preamble`, but still want to have this two coloured construct.
Just using theorem will give me a `Theorem:trial` in the upper part.

[image: newtheorem]

Comment: Have you looked in the manual at the `block` environment?

Comment: Ah..no! But thats what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AndrewStacey an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `block` environment from `beamer`.  It's documented in Section 12.3 of the manual (for version 3.31).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147398/86}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{block}{Block Title}
Block body
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Madrid theme to make it more obvious.)

[image: Block in beamer]